# Depth First Search for adjacency list in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, depth-first-search

I have a list that is structured as follows:

```
0 ; (0,0,G) ; []
1 ; (9,0,B) ; []
2 ; (9,9,R) ; []
3 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
4 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
5 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
6 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
7 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
8 ; (-1,-1,E) ; []
```

Each item in the list has an index, a tuple and a list of its nearby neighbors which contains the neighbor's index.

My search begins at either index 1 or index 2 and I need all the paths from them to index 0. Additionally, I also need a list that contains all the indices along the path.

I have used recursion to implement this and am using a global mutable variable(blueChains) to store all the possible paths. I want to do the same without using a global variable but instead, I want the function to return the list of all paths as its causing problems in other parts of my code.

This is how my function looks:

```
let rec traverseBlue index visited = 

    match index with 
    | 0 ->
        let newVisited = 0 :: visited
        blueChains <- newVisited :: blueChains
        printfn "Golden Cog Reached! Blue wins the game!"
        currentGameStatus <- WonByB 
    | ind -> 
        if not (List.contains ind visited) then
            let newVisited = ind :: visited
            blueChains <- newVisited :: blueChains
            printfn "INDEX: %i VISITED: %A" ind newVisited
            for i in tree.[ind].connectedNodes do
                traverseBlue i newVisited
```

The output that I get is:

```
INDEX: 1 VISITED: [1]
INDEX: 3 VISITED: [3; 1]
BLUE CHAINS : [[1]; [1; 3]]
```

I want to get this same value for blue chains but without the use of a global variable

Comment: This doesn't seem all that contingent on the specifics of depth-first-search. It seems like you just need to pass it as an argument, like you already do with `visited`, and then returning it when you're done. Are you having any specific problems doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying

Comment: You're already carrying state between recursive calls with the `visited` argument, right? So just do that with `blueChains` too. Then all you need to do is return the final value of `blueChains` when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I finally did thanks to @glennsl that solved my problem.

```
let rec traverseBlue index visited oldBlueChains = 

let mutable blueChains = []
match index with 
| 0 ->
    let newVisited = 0 :: visited
    blueChains <- newVisited :: oldBlueChains
    printfn "Golden Cog Reached! Blue wins the game!"
    currentGameStatus <- WonByB 
    blueChains
| ind -> 
    if not (List.contains ind visited) then
        let newVisited = ind :: visited
        blueChains <- newVisited :: oldBlueChains
        printfn "INDEX: %i VISITED: %A" ind newVisited
        for i in tree.[ind].connectedNodes do
            blueChains <- (traverseBlue i newVisited blueChains) @ blueChains
```